# The requested URL /var/www/android_connect was not found on this server on AWS ec2 instance while connecting from android studio

Tags: php, mysql, linux, android-studio, amazon-ec2

I have PHP installed on AWS EC2 instance and wanted to connect to MYSQL from android studio using PHP. I have copied all the .php files to /var/www/android_connect folder. But not able to access getting error as 
404 Not Found. 
The requested URL /var/www/android_connect/login_status.php was not found on this server.
I have inbound and outbound traffic allowed for http. Apache service is up and running and able to get starting page. But sub directories are not found. How can I resolve the issue? Do we need to change any configuration settings or permissions?

Comment: you wont find `/var/ww/..` but ip or `localhost/android_connect/...`

Comment: check the path. it slould be your ip/main_foldername/filename.php